# Groovy/Spock- Data driven test for values from excel sheet

Tags: groovy, spock

I could definitely use some help here. I have an excel sheet from where I am getting values and doing some validations on them, I am checking if both values match. My code is as follows:

```
@Unroll ("For #calcToCheck.tr_date_class")
def "I check flag value #calcToCheck.tr_date "(CalculationClass calcToCheck) {        
    expect:
    flag==calcToCheck.result

    where:
    calcToCheck << calInputParameters()
}

def calInputParameters() {
    //some logic to get values from SQL and getting flag
    return calcsToCheck
}
```

This runs fine for one row but when I insert multiple rows in excel sheet, I just get output as one result. I would like to see each row's result. I thought adding `@Unroll` would take care of it showing me what rows it is displaying the results but it does not.

Comment: What is the type of `calcsToCheck`?

Comment: def calcsToCheck = new ArrayList<CalculationClass>, it works with one row but with more than one row, although the result is what I want, I do not see each row in IDE's Run tab

Comment: Try to debug your `calInputParameters()` method to make sure you have many `CalculationClass` objects. The test looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some sample code you can run and then modify. Because you did not explain where `flag` comes from, I was just making up something, assuming it is also an unrolled parameter checked against whatever your helper method delivers.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

/**
 * See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48410722/1082681
 */
class PseudoExcelTableTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll//("For #calcToCheck.tr_date_class")
  def "I check flag value #calcToCheck.tr_date"(CalculationClass calcToCheck, int flag) {
    expect:
    flag == calcToCheck.result

    where:
    calcToCheck << calInputParameters()
    flag << [11, 22, 33]
  }

  def calInputParameters() {
    def calcsToCheck = new ArrayList<CalculationClass>()
    calcsToCheck.addAll(
      new CalculationClass(result: 11, tr_date: "eleven", tr_date_class: "short"),
      new CalculationClass(result: 22, tr_date: "twenty-two", tr_date_class: "long"),
      new CalculationClass(result: 33, tr_date: "thirty-three", tr_date_class: "normal")
    )
    return calcsToCheck
  }

  static class CalculationClass {
    int result
    String tr_date
    String tr_date_class
  }
}
```

As for the unrolled method names, you mix up two things:

- Naming the methods via `@Unroll` parameter, which in my example would result in method names `For short`, `For long`, `For normal`. This has preference over the second option:
- Naming the methods via normal method name, which in my example would result in method names `I check flag value eleven`, `I check flag value twenty-two`, `I check flag value thirty-three`.

I chose option 2 by commenting out the unroll parameter.

Comment: Let me use this logic and see what happens, thank you for your help

Comment: Kriegaex, your solution helped. I took 1st option. thanks.